# Can I use elfinder to browse items from database like mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, elfinder

Instead of using elfinder to browse files. Can I use elfinder to browse Items from database like MySQL.

I'm working on MVC.net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not with elFinder, no, but you can use other open source tools such as Adminer, which works very nicely. Adminer requires PHP.

https://www.adminer.org/

Note this is for general overall DBA tasks for the person running the site, if your aim is to provide limited access to update and retrieve things out of MySQL for end-users usually people code this up themselves, half the web is app servers querying MySQL for stuff.